# Sum of all rows in specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate the sum of all rows in a specific column in pandas.  I am doing the project using a jupyterhub notebook.

The following code below generates a full list with the value in each row and not the total of all rows.  Curious to know what I am doing wrong?

```
ria_aum_total = ria_aum['5F(2)(a)'].sum()

print(ria_aum_total)
```

Comment: `ria_aum['5F(2)(a)'].sum(axis=0)`?

Comment: nope. same thing, just a really long list of the rows in the columns. Really strange

Comment: Maybe is not typed as float. `ria_aum['5F(2)(a)'].astype(float).sum(axis=0)`

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '996,764,385.00'.  This will be a very large total in the trillions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast as float but first, remove the commas:

```
df['5F(2)(a)'] = df['5F(2)(a)'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float).sum()
```

Comment: got it!! thank you very much for you help.  Very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

According to Pandas documentation you have to use Pandas Dataframe. Here is the example given in the documentation you have to cast the data to Dataframe and then you can use the .sum of the DataFrame datastructure.

Here is the example from the documentation (https://www.javatpoint.com/pandas-sum):

```
import pandas as pd      
info = {'Name': ['Parker', 'Smith', 'William'],   'age' : [32, 28, 39]}     
data = pd.DataFrame(info)     
data['total'] = data['age'].sum()     
print(data)
```